# Land use/type information from here maps

Tags: gis, here-api

Given a region in a map, is it possible to get data allowing me to say something like 40% is water 10% is forrest, 30% is city and 20% is open land... as an example. I know of other systems (Mapbox for one) which lets you get this land use information, but I have not seen as much as a hint that this is obtainable through the here map api.

Does anyone know how I could go about getting that type of information? To boil it down, I need to classify a circle around a position according to how many viable emergency landing options a small airplane might have from that position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Platform Data Extension API to get the outline of land and water bodies (CARTO-POLY layers in PDE). You have to write your own logic for calculating the percentages though. But for your usecase to figure out emergency landing options PDE can be used. You can view all the PDE layers of our latest version using tcs.ext.here.com/pde/layers?region=WEU&release=18129&url_root=pde.api.here.com.

```
http://pde.cit.api.here.com/1/doc/layers.json?region=EU&release=2014Q4
&app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}
&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}
```

Read more about the extension in the developer site. Happy Coding!

Comment: That does look promising, but when looking at the available layers as per https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/topics/example-layer.html I see a lot related to roads, but nothing about forrest, city or water. Can you guide me to where I would find that kind of information?

Comment: Previous comment was a little too quick. New one would read: Your link leads to an empty result [], but looking at the api info, it seems that the layers are available https://pde.api.here.com/1/doc/attributes.json?app_id=XXXX&app_code=XXX leads to layer info containing things such as "900130 : Park (State)<br/>900140 : Park in Water<br/>900150". Now the issue seems to more be that there are too many categories ;-)
I will check that I am actually able to extract usable info before closing the question for good, but it looks promising

Comment: Hmm, upon further investigation, I am really not sure exactly how to approach such queries. Would it be possible to give a quick example, for example retrieving forrest or water, or similar, for a certain small region?

Comment: Ok, well, I guess the question is answered, even if I cannot figure out to use it, so I will mark is as such for now.

Comment: Using places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/categories/places?at=41.8369%2C-87.684&app_id={YOUR-APP-ID}&app_code={YOUR-APP-CODE} you can find all the categories available for a position and use the category id in your API to find nearby places.